# Android app compatibility issues with Nexus 6

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

For supporting For Nexus 6 screen size and density, I have the following in my manifest:

```
    <compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

The complete list of values in my manifest are listed below. Google Play says my app is incompatible. Not sure what I am missing here..

```
 <compatible-screens>
                    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="213" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" />
                    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640" />
                </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: How did you solve this, please? I have added `<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />` but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a lot of trouble too to make my app works on Nexus 6. I finally found how to do it, hopefully it will work for you.

1. First of all, you need to set the screenDensity to 560 in the AndroidManifest for compatible-screens. It didn't work without specifying it in the screenDensity list. I had to set the screen size to normal with a density of 560 to make it work.
2. Then, I had to provide xxhdpi (and maybe xxxhdpi) icons for the application. I provided both icons at the same time so I don't know if the xxxhdpi is mandatory. But on this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html, it is said that you should provide at least a xxxhdpi icon.